# PowerBi HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powerbi-embedded

I'm following the PowerBI Developer In A Day tutorial attempting to embed a sample dashboard into an MVC app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/learning-catalog/developer-online-course

After a few times of going back over each section and ensuring that all of the permissions are correct in Azure, Azure AD, PowerBi, and my appsettings.json, I've been unable to resolve this issue. It seems to throw the Bad Request error whenever creating the embedToken.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code
> 'BadRequest'
> Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.EmbedTokenOperations.GenerateTokenWithHttpMessagesAsync(GenerateTokenRequestV2
> requestParameters, Dictionary<string, List> customHeaders,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing HttpOperationException: Operation
> returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
> Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.EmbedTokenOperations.GenerateTokenWithHttpMessagesAsync(GenerateTokenRequestV2
> requestParameters, Dictionary<string, List> customHeaders,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.EmbedTokenOperationsExtensions.GenerateTokenAsync(IEmbedTokenOperations
> operations, GenerateTokenRequestV2 requestParameters,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> PowerBiEmbed.Services.PowerBiApiService.GetReportsEmbeddingData() in
> PowerBiApiService.cs
> +
> string embedToken = (await client.EmbedToken.GenerateTokenAsync(tokenRequest)).Token;
> SalesReportsDemo.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in
> HomeController.cs
> +
> var viewModel = await _powerBiApiService.GetReportsEmbeddingData(); Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[]
> arguments) System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, ValueTask actionResultValueTask)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref
> State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
> next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

The class where the error is occurring:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api;
using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PowerBiEmbed.Models;
using PowerBiEmbed.ViewModels;

namespace PowerBiEmbed.Services
{
    public class PowerBiApiService
    {
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
        private Uri _powerBiServiceApiRootUrl;
        private Guid _workspaceId;
            
        public const string PowerBiDefaultScope = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default";

        public PowerBiApiService(IConfiguration configuration, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _powerBiServiceApiRootUrl = new Uri(configuration["PowerBi:ServiceRootUrl"]);
            _workspaceId = new Guid(configuration["PowerBi:WorkspaceId"]);
            _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        }

        public string GetAccessToken()
        {
            return _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForAppAsync(PowerBiDefaultScope).Result;
        }

        public PowerBIClient GetPowerBiClient()
        {
            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(GetAccessToken(), "Bearer");
            
            return new PowerBIClient(_powerBiServiceApiRootUrl, tokenCredentials);
        }

        public async Task<WorkspaceViewModel> GetReportsEmbeddingData()
        {
            // Connect to Power BI
            var client = GetPowerBiClient();
            
            // Get reports in the workspace
            var reports = (await client.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(_workspaceId)).Value;
            
            var reportList = new List<EmbeddedReport>();
            var reportTokenRequests = new List<GenerateTokenRequestV2Report>();
            
            foreach (var report in reports)
            {
                reportList.Add(new EmbeddedReport
                {
                    Id = report.Id.ToString(),
                    Name = report.Name,
                    EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl
                });
                
                reportTokenRequests.Add(new GenerateTokenRequestV2Report(report.Id, allowEdit: true));
            }
            
            // Get datasets in the workspace
            var datasets = (await client.Datasets.GetDatasetsInGroupAsync(_workspaceId)).Value;
            
            var datasetList = new List<EmbeddedDataset>();
            var datasetTokenRequests = new List<GenerateTokenRequestV2Dataset>();
            
            foreach (var dataset in datasets)
            {
                datasetList.Add(new EmbeddedDataset
                {
                    Id = dataset.Id.ToString(),
                    Name = dataset.Name,
                    EmbedUrl = dataset.QnaEmbedURL
                });
                
                datasetTokenRequests.Add(new GenerateTokenRequestV2Dataset(dataset.Id));
            }
            
            // Generate token request for the workspace
            var workspaceRequests = new GenerateTokenRequestV2TargetWorkspace[] {
                new GenerateTokenRequestV2TargetWorkspace(_workspaceId)
            };
            
            // Bundle token requests for reports, datasets, and the workspace
            var tokenRequest = new GenerateTokenRequestV2(
                reports: reportTokenRequests,
                datasets: datasetTokenRequests,
                targetWorkspaces: workspaceRequests
            );
            
            // Generate the embed token
            string embedToken = (await client.EmbedToken.GenerateTokenAsync(tokenRequest)).Token;
            
            // Return report embedding data to caller
            return new WorkspaceViewModel
            {
                ReportsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reportList),
                DatasetsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datasetList),
                EmbedToken = embedToken
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had faced to that same 'BadRequest' studying PowerBI Developer In A Day tutorial.
In this case, the problem is occurred by lack of **EffectiveIdentity** for each Dataset.

Before generating TokenRequest, you need to generate EffectiveIdentity too.

The following sample code could solve your problem.

```
var effectiveIdentities = new List<EffectiveIdentity>();
foreach (var dataset in datasets)
{
    if ((bool)dataset.IsEffectiveIdentityRequired)
    {
        // If Dataset requires EffectiveIdentity, you need to add it.
        effectiveIdentities.Add(new EffectiveIdentity(
            username: <username>,
            roles: new List<string>{ <roles> },
            datasets: new List<string> { dataset.Id.ToString() }
        ));
    }
}

var tokenRequest = new GenerateTokenRequestV2(
    reports: reportTokenRequests,
    datasets: datasetTokenRequests,
    targetWorkspaces: workspaceRequests,

    //When generating token, set EffectiveIdentities.
    identities: effectiveIdentities
);
```

These also help you.

- [Embed Token - Generate Token - REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/generate-token)
- [Solved: 400 Bad Request Error when embedding report - Microsoft Power BI Community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/400-Bad-Request-Error-when-embedding-report/m-p/1060029)

Comment: Super thanks, so applying a role even from powerbi service which is possible new though the new option into edit mode of the report also changes this dataset property.