# Power BI Embedding with RLS - BadRequest Error

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I'm facing an issue while trying to embed a Power BI report with Row-Level Security (RLS) policies enabled using C# in a Blazor app. The code I've written is resulting in a "BadRequest" error, and I could use some guidance to troubleshoot and resolve this issue.

Here's a snippet of my code:

// [protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
try
{
if (firstRender)
{
var result = new PowerBIEmbedConfig();

```
            // Authenticate using created credentials
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;

            authenticationResult = await DoAuthentication();

            var tokenCredentials =
                new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");

            using (var client = new PowerBIClient(
                new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com/"), tokenCredentials))
            {
                var report =
                    await client.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(
                        new Guid(workspaceId),
                        new Guid(reportId));

                var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(
                    accessLevel: "edit",
                    allowSaveAs: true,
                    datasetId: datasetId,
                    identities: new List<EffectiveIdentity>
                        {
                    new EffectiveIdentity(
                        username: "a9638d14-85ba-47db-b448-9b739ef4d274",
                        roles: new List<string> { "UseID" }
                        //datasets: datasetId
                    )
                        }
                );

                var tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenAsync(
                    new Guid(workspaceId),
                    new Guid(reportId),
                    generateTokenRequestParameters
                );

                result.EmbedToken = tokenResponse;
                result.EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl;
                result.Id = report.Id.ToString();

                await Interop.CreateReport(
                    JSRuntime,
                    PowerBIElement,
                    tokenResponse.Token,
                    report.EmbedUrl,
                    report.Id.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpOperationException ex)
    {
        // Log the detailed error information
        Console.WriteLine($"Detailed Error: {ex.Response.Content}");
        throw; // Re-throw the exception after logging
    }
}


private const string AuthorityFormat = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0";
private const string MSGraphScope = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default";

private async Task<AuthenticationResult> DoAuthentication()
{
    IConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient;

    daemonClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientID)
        .WithAuthority(string.Format(AuthorityFormat, TenantID))
        .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
        .Build();

    AuthenticationResult authResult =
        await daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { MSGraphScope }).ExecuteAsync();

    return authResult;
}
```

}
]

The specific error message I'm encountering is:

Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperations.GenerateTokenInGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync(Guid groupId, Guid reportId, GenerateTokenRequest requestParameters, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
// [Additional Stack Trace]

Any code or article are ok

Comment: The issue is with the Request while generating the Embed token.  Please verify you're passing correct effective Identity. Refer to this issue and it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690094/powerbi-httpoperationexception-operation-returned-an-invalid-status-code-badre

Comment: LMK if the problem still exists